# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Reports log for Windows Phone 8 display a USER_AGENT than other environments

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

My team is facing some layout issues on Windows Phone 8 for our App that extensively uses JQuery 1.3.1, which by the way works like a charm on Android and iOS.

Doing some investigation we noticed the USER_AGENT column on the reports table APP_ACTIVITY_REPORT is missing a bit of info comparing to similar entries for other OS.

Android

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; pt-br; GT-N8000 Build/JZO54K)
>   AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Safari/534.30/**Worklight/6.0.0**

iOS

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11A501
>   (391584416)/Worklight/6.0.0 Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac
>   OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11A501
>   (384361824)**/Worklight/6.0.0**

Windows Phone 8

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0;
>   IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 720) ***<---- NO WORKLIGHT
>   STRING PRESENT***

The question is more about if for some reason this **/Worklight/6.0.0** segment present on both Android and iOS indicates that something is wrong with the WP8 environment, which could be affecting the performance of jQuery Mobile WP8 app in Worklight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Worklight" string in the user agent is used for supporting IBM WebSphere Portal and it is not related to anything else you have mentioned re jQuery Mobile performance in Windows Phone 8.

The "Worklight" string does not appear in the Windows Phone 8 user agent because it was not implemented to be there. Again, this is of no consequence to you in regards to this question.